# How can I take advantage of ServiceFabric Autorefresh?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I recently read about ServiceFabric offering some kind of Autorefresh mode, considering its infrastructure and the cluster running independently.

So, according to what I've wrote, all I need to do it go to my project, check the properties and set the "Application Debug Mode" to `Refresh Application`.

Basically that is what I did now, but I don't quite see the difference. There's no repackaging happening at all.

Do I have to run some kind of cmdlet in the background, as it is the case with e.g. `webpack watch`?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I mostly thought as soon as a trigger gets pulled, may it be save or a manual button, a new package is built to replace the current deployment package. However, safe to say I wouldn't know how it would be possible to replace stuff like debug symbols etc on the fly

Comment: I am not sure in which context you expect something to happen. It is only useful when doing F5 debugging on a single node development 'cluster'. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio#application-debug-modes).

Comment: @Peter that's what I'm running it in. But there is no refresh happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio) explains **Refresh Application** as follow.

> **Refresh Application** This mode enables you to quickly change and debug
>   your code and supports editing static web files while debugging. This
>   mode only works if your local development cluster is in 1-Node mode.
>   This is the default Application Debug Mode.

On other *application debug* options, Visual Studio creates a package and deploy it to the cluster and register the application to run on Service Fabric, the package will contain all binaries compiled that are needed to run the application.

The main difference between the *Refresh Application* and the others, is that the package created is a symbolic link to the source in the Dev machine, you are not actually copying the package with the binaries, when you change the static files, it will be the same files used by the deployed application in SF, this will make more flexible to make changes without repackaging, registering and deploying the application on every change.

> PS: It does not work the same way as the watch feature for nodeJs development, it is just to avoid the package deployment. You could just reload the page though.

[This post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/04/17/speed-up-service-fabric-development-with-the-new-refresh-application-debug-mode-2/) explain in more details.